How many turns will it take for this coin flipping game to end?
Here is a problem (coin flipping game) I recently thought about.
Suppose there are 2 Discrete Time Markov Chains:

Markov Chain A (3-state chain):

$$
X_t  = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1/3 & 1/3 & 1/3 \\
1/3 & 1/3 & 1/3 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Markov Chain B (4-state chain):
$$
Y_t  = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1/4 & 1/4 & 1/4 & 1/4 \\
1/4 & 1/4 & 1/4 & 1/4 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
1/4 & 1/4 & 1/4 & 1/4 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

In this problem, we start in Chain A in state 1.

At each new time point, we flip a 2-sided fair coin : If heads, we stay in the same state we are currently in but move to Chain B. If tails, we stay in Chain A.
The first time we move from Chain A to Chain B, we permanently stay in Chain B
Once we reach State 3 (whether in Chain A or in Chain B), we stop forever.

I tried to represent all of this mathematically:
$$
B_t = 
\begin{cases} 
1 & \text{with probability } p \\
0 & \text{with probability } 1-p 
\end{cases}
$$
$$
S_t = \sum_{i=0}^{t} B_i
$$
$$
Z_t = 
\begin{cases} 
X_t & \text{if } S_t = 0 \\
Y_t & \text{if } S_t \geq 1 
\end{cases}
$$
$$
T = \min \{ t \geq 0 : Z_t = 3 \}
$$
Based on this, I am interested in answering the following types of questions:

On average, what percent of the time will $Z_t$ stop in $X_t$ vs $Y_t$?
Is it possible to find out the joint probability distribution of (number of steps to switch from $X_t$ to $Y_t$, number of steps for process to stop)?

I am not sure how to answer these questions, so I wrote R simulations to try and answer them numerically. For example:
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)


simulate_markov_chain <- function(simulation_num) {
    # Transition matrices
    transition_matrix_A <- matrix(c(1/3, 1/3, 1/3,  # probabilities from state 1
                                    1/3, 1/3, 1/3,  # probabilities from state 2
                                    0,   0,   1),   # probabilities from state 3
                                  nrow = 3, byrow = TRUE)
    
    transition_matrix_B <- matrix(c(1/4, 1/4, 1/4, 1/4,  # probabilities from state 1
                                    1/4, 1/4, 1/4, 1/4,  # probabilities from state 2
                                    0,   0,   1,   0,    # probabilities from state 3
                                    1/4, 1/4, 1/4, 1/4), # probabilities from state 4
                                  nrow = 4, byrow = TRUE)
    
    # Initial state and chain
    state <- 1
    chain <- "A"
    
   
    path_df <- data.frame(iteration = 1, chain = chain, state = state)
    
    # Simulate 
    iteration <- 1
    while (state != 3) {
        # Flip a coin
        coin_flip <- sample(c("heads", "tails"), size = 1, prob = c(0.5, 0.5))
        
        # Check if switch to chain B
        if (coin_flip == "heads" || chain == "B") {
            chain <- "B"
            state <- sample(1:4, size = 1, prob = transition_matrix_B[state, ])
        } else {
            state <- sample(1:3, size = 1, prob = transition_matrix_A[state, ])
        }
        
       
        iteration <- iteration + 1
        path_df <- rbind(path_df, data.frame(iteration = iteration, chain = chain, state = state))
    }
    
   
    path_df$simulation_num <- simulation_num
    
    return(path_df)
}



# simulation 1000 times 
results <- map_dfr(1:1000, simulate_markov_chain)




############################################################


results <- results %>%
    group_by(simulation_num) %>%
    mutate(transition_iteration = ifelse(chain == "B" & lag(chain) == "A", iteration, NA),
           max_iteration = max(iteration)) %>%
    ungroup()



transition_iterations <- results %>% 
    group_by(simulation_num) %>% 
    summarise(transition_iteration = min(transition_iteration, na.rm = TRUE),
              max_iteration = max(iteration))


# Filter out rows with Inf values
transition_iterations <- transition_iterations %>% filter(!is.infinite(transition_iteration), !is.infinite(max_iteration))

density_estimate <- MASS::kde2d(x = transition_iterations$transition_iteration, 
                                y = transition_iterations$max_iteration, 
                                n = 100)

filled.contour(x = density_estimate$x, 
               y = density_estimate$y, 
               z = density_estimate$z, 
               color.palette = colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(9, "Greens")),
               plot.title = title(main = "Contour Plot of Transition Iteration vs Max Iteration",
                                  xlab = "Transition Iteration", 
                                  ylab = "Max Iteration"),
               plot.axes = {axis(1); axis(2); })


As we can see, the majority of the games finish relatively early on (i.e. bottom left corner of the plot).
Note that sometimes $Z_t$ never transitions to $Y_t$ therefore the transition time is Infinite and I had to remove these rows for the simulation. I am not sure if a probability distribution can be defined with such infinite values.
But analytically (i.e. without simulations), is it possible to answer the following questions?

On average, what percent of the time will $Z_t$ stop in $X_t$ vs $Y_t$? (i.e. stopping in Chain A vs stopping in Chain B)
Is it possible to find out the joint probability distribution of (number of steps to switch from $X_t$ to $Y_t$, number of steps for process to stop)?
Within a given simulation, after $n$ turns of playing the game, what is the probability we are in Chain A?

Normally I would have used the Fundamental Matrix approach (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_Markov_chain), but I am not sure if it can be applied here.
Thanks!
Note: I made this visualization for the percent of games in Chain A vs Chain B as the number of turns in a simulation increase:
library(ggplot2)
chain_counts <- results %>%
    group_by(iteration, chain) %>%
    summarise(n = n(), .groups = "drop")

total_counts <- results %>%
    group_by(iteration) %>%
    summarise(total = n(), .groups = "drop")

percentages <- inner_join(chain_counts, total_counts, by = "iteration") %>%
    mutate(percentage = n / total * 100)


ggplot(percentages, aes(x = iteration, y = percentage, fill = chain)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
    labs(x = "Simulation Number", y = "Percentage", fill = "Chain") +
    theme_minimal() +
    scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1") +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(min(percentages$iteration), max(percentages$iteration), by = 1)) +ggtitle("Length of Game vs Percentage of Games in Chain A/ Chain B")



Having flipped the coin to decide if you stay in A or go to B it looks like you roll a 3 or 4 sided die to decide which state you move to, right?  For the questions you list, you can make a new Markov chain.  It has two absorbing states, one if you go to 3 in A and one if you go to B.  It has only three states, so solving it by hand should not be hard.

thank you Ross ... can you please write an answer if you have time?

The "step" is not clearly defined (for me). To ask a question on this, i will introduce the notations $1A,2A,3A$ for the states in $A$ and $1B,2B,3B,4B$ for the states in $B$. Now we start playing. We are in $1A$. Do we first flip a coin (step "F") or go one step with the transition from $1A$ to some other $jA$ (step "A")? Now i suppose we do the same for all other steps. When we land in $B$ there is also a step "B" which brings us from $jB$ to some $kB$, if not already terminal. And from now on, we have three questions, am i understanding them correctly? (1) : Which is the probability...

(1)... to stop in $3A$ (versus $3B$) (2) Mean time of first hitting $1B,2B,3B,4B$ (if at all), for me "switching from $X_t$ to $Y_t$ is unclear, and respectively first hit of $3A,3B$, (an expliciti formula is needed ?!) (3) Probability $P_n$ that (after exactly $n$ steps "F+A" or "A+F" - to be made clear for the other point (1) - where it matters) we are still in $1A,2A,3A$. So for instance $P_0=1$, $P_1=1/2$...

We have too many states, denoted for a short time (as in my comment) by

$1A$, $2A$, $3A$ for the states in the "block" $A$,
$1B$, $2B$, $3B$, $4B$ for the states in the "block" $B$,

so let us put together those that have similar meaning for a gambler, obtaining a simple(r) modelling Markov chain with only four states:

The state $3A$ is final, we denote it by $FA$.
The states $1A$, and $2A$ have similar meanings, the game keeps runnging, we use $RA$ for them as a block.
The state $3B$ is final, we denote it by $FB$.
The states $1B$, $2B$, and $4B$ have similar meanings, the game keeps runnging, we use $RB$ for them as a block.

We use the order $RA,FA,RB,FB$ for the states. (Although it would be better for some purposes to have $FA,FB$ at last places, so that some matrices we write have the corresponding block with a unit matrix.)

Next, we have to give a clear sense to a "step". For this we distinguish between the operations:

the "(coin) flip" operation $F$, and
the "(Markov chain) move" operation $M$ (which is either an $A$-move inside the $A$ block, or a $B$-move inside the $B$ block).

As described, when we are in $3A$ we stay there, an absorbant state unchanged by the flip. So the passage matrices for the two operations $F,M$ are:
$$
F = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1/2 & 0 & 1/2 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}
\ ,\qquad
M = 
\begin{bmatrix}
2/3 & 1/3 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 3/4 & 1/4 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}
\ .
$$
Now what is a step?
It is a combined operation, involving both $F,M$. But in which order. Depending on the order, we have the transition matrices $A=FM$, and $B=MF$ - hopefully not to be mixed with the blocks A and B of the "game" we play:
$$
A = FM = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1/3 & 1/6 & 3/8 & 1/8\\
0 & \boxed 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 3/4 & 1/4 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \boxed 1 
\end{bmatrix}
\ ,\qquad
B = MF = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1/3 & 1/3 & 1/3 & 0\\
0 & \boxed 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 3/4 & 1/4 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \boxed 1 
\end{bmatrix}
\ .
$$
The boxed one-entries correspond to the absorbant final states $FA,FB$.
We will now address the OP questions for both cases, since there is no big difference. Although i am guessing that $B=MF$ is the case of interest, its picture being:
    1/3
    __
   ´  `
   \  /    1/3
  1=RA ----->---- FA=2                    RA = 1A + 2A
    |                                     FA = 3A
    |
    |
    V 1/3
    |
    |                                     RB = 1B + 2B + 4B
  3=RB ----->---- FB=4                    FB = 3B
   /  \     1/4
   `--´
    3/4

And we will use below in computations also $1,2,3,4$ instead of $RA,FA,RB,FB$ respectively.

To have easy notations, recall we use numbers $1,2,3,4$ for the states $RA,FA,RB,FB$ respectively.
Let $p_S$ be the probability that starting in the state $S$ the terminal $FA$ is reached.
OP asks in a first question for $p_1=p_{RA}$, the probability that starting in $RA$ we are reaching the final state $FA$ from the $A$-chain.
Then we have the linear system for the transition matrix $B$:
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
p_1 &= \frac 13p_1+\frac 13p_2+\frac 13p_3\ ,\\
p_2 &= 1\ ,\\
p_3 &= \frac 34p_3+\frac 14p_4\ ,\\
p_4 &= 0\ .
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
Then $p_3=0$ (and we could have written it directly), so $p_1=\frac 12$.
When working with $A$ instead (of $B$), $p_{2,3,4}$ are the same, and $p_1$ is determined by the first equation:
$$
p_1 = \frac 13p_1+\frac 16p_2+\frac 38p_3+\frac 18p_4\ ,
$$
which leads to $\frac 23p_1=\frac 16p_2$,
$p_1=\frac 14p_2=\frac 14$.

Let $\tau_B$ be the stopping time of hitting for the first time the block $B$.
Let $P(N)=\Bbb P(\tau_B=N)$ be the probability that after exacly $N$ steps the current state is in the $B$-block. Then:

Case $B$:
$$
P(N) = \left(\frac 13\right)^{N-1}\cdot \left(\frac 13+0\right)\ .
$$

Case $A$:
$$
P(N) = \left(\frac 13\right)^{N-1}\cdot \left(\frac 38+\frac 18\right)\ .
$$



The second question
can be restated as follows. Fix two "numbers" $N,M$, the value $\infty$ for $N$ being also allowed. We need the probability that our game moves from the block A to the block B at step $N$ (where $N=\infty$ means it never does it), and the terminal state is reached at step $M$.
We distinguish the cases:

$N=\infty$. Then the process never moves to block B, thus terminates in $FA$ at step $M$, the probability for this event being $(1/3)^{M-1}\cdot (1/3)$ when the transition matrix is $B$, and half of it,  $(1/3)^{M-1}\cdot (1/6)$
when we work with $A$ instead.
$N<\infty$, so a transition to the B-block occurs, and so
we are reaching the final state $FB$ from the B-chain to terminate after further $K>0$ steps, $K=M-N$. (If $K\le 0$ the probability vanishes.) Else it is $(1/3)^{N-1}\cdot(1/3)\cdot(3/4)^{K-1}\cdot (1/4)$ when the transition is done via $B$, and instead, in the case the transition is $A$ we have
$(1/3)^{N-1}\cdot(3/8)\cdot(3/4)^{K-1}\cdot (1/4)$ .


The third question gives a fixed $n$ and asks for still being in block A at step $n$, so $\tau_B>n$.
What is $\Bbb P(\tau_B>n)$? With about notations it is $P(n+1)+P(n+2)+\dots$ - or we can add the probabilities for being either in $RA$ after $n$ steps, or having passed for the first time in $FA$ at step $j\le n$. We obtain the sum:
$$
\left(\frac 13\right)^n
+
\sum_{1\le j\le n}\left(\frac 13\right)^{j-1}
\cdot \left(\frac 13\right)\ ,
$$
when $B$ is the transition, respectively
$$
\left(\frac 13\right)^n
+
\sum_{1\le j\le n}\left(\frac 13\right)^{j-1}
\cdot \left(\frac 16\right)\ ,
$$
when the transition is $A$.

For your first question you ask you have a three position Markov chain.  Position $1$ is the start.  Position $2$ is Chain $A$, state $3$ and position $3$ is Chain $B$, all positions.  Positions $2$ and $3$ are absorbing.  From start, you go to $3$ with probability $\frac 12$ on the coin flip.  You go to $2$ with probability $\frac 16$, with a factor $12$ from the coin flip and a factor $\frac 13$ from the die roll to pick state $3$.  You return to start with probability $\frac 13$.
We can ignore the returns to start to see that the chance you end in position $2$ is $\frac 14$ and the chance you end in position $3$ is $\frac 34$.
For the second and third questions your Markov chain gains one state.  You split the old position $3$ into position $3$ which is Chain $B$, not in state $3$ and position $4$, which is Chain $B$, position $4$.  Positions $2$ and $4$ are absorbing.  The probabilities from start are $\frac 13$ to return to start, $\frac 16$ to position $2, \frac 38$ to position $3$, and $\frac 18$ to position $4$.  From position $3$ it is $\frac 34$ to return to position $3$ and $\frac 14$ to move to position $4$ and end.
The chance you move from Chain $A$ to Chain $B$ on move $n$ is $\left ( \frac 13 \right )^{n-1}\cdot \frac 12$ where the first factor comes from $n-1$ returns to start and the second comes from the final tails on the coin flip.  You can sum this to get the chance you are on Chain $B$ after $n$ moves.  Subtracting from $1$ gives the chance you are in Chain $A$ after $n$ moves.  As $n \to \infty$ the chance you are in Chain $B$ approaches $\frac 34$ as it should from the first paragraph.
